# Matplotlib with dates - changing labels and ticks for monthly data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this:

```
data_ = list(range(106))
index_ =  pd.period_range('3/1/2004', '12/1/2012', freq='M')
df2_ = pd.DataFrame(data = data_, index = index_, columns = ['data'])
```

I want to plot this dataframe. Currently, I am using:

```
df2_.plot()
```

Now I like to control the labels (and possibly ticks) at the x axis. In particular, I like to have monthly ticks at the axis and possibly a label at every other month or quarterly labels. I also like to have vertical grid lines.

I started looking at [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_convert.html) but I am already failing at constructing the timedelta.

Comment: This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704366/how-to-change-the-datetime-tick-label-frequency-for-matplotlib-plots/).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With regards to constructing the timedelta, `datetime.timdelta()` doesn’t have a parameter to specify months, so it’s probably convenient to stick to `pd.date_range()`. However, I found that objects of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` don’t play nice with matplotlib ticks so you could convert them to `datetime.date` objects like so

```
index_ = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%Y-%m-%d').date() 
        for date in pd.date_range('2004-03-01', '2012-12-01', freq="M")]
```

It’s possible to add gridlines and customise axes labels by first defining a matplotlib axes object, and then passing this to `DataFrame.plot()`

```
ax = plt.axes()
df2_.plot(ax=ax)
```

Now you can add vertical gridlines to your plot

```
ax.xaxis.grid(True)
```

And specify quarterly xticks labels by using `matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator` and setting the interval to 3

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator(interval=3))
```

And finally, I found the ticks to be to be very crowded so I formatted them to get a nicer fit

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b %y'))
labels = ax.get_xticklabels()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=85, fontsize=8)
```

To produce the following:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks. Can I ask you to describe what the list comprehension at the top does exactly?

Comment: Sure, so for each date in `pd.date_range('2004-03-01', '2012-12-01', freq=“M”)`, convert from type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp` to `datetime.date`. I did this because the tick labels weren’t showing correctly on the plot when passed in as pandas timestamps.

Comment: No need to change the index and no need to create the Axes with matplotlib. Do this instead: `ax = df2_.plot(x_compat=True)`