# How to get ticks every hour

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider this simple example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

pd.__version__
Out[147]: u'0.22.0'

idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 05:03', '2017-01-01 18:03', freq = 'min')

df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(idx)),  index = idx)
df.head()
Out[145]: 
2017-01-01 05:03:00   0.4361
2017-01-01 05:04:00   0.9737
2017-01-01 05:05:00   0.8430
2017-01-01 05:06:00   0.4292
2017-01-01 05:07:00   0.5739
Freq: T, dtype: float64
```

I want to plot this, and have ticks every hour. I use:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)  #
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

df.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
```

which gives

[image]

why dont the ticks appear every hour here? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should play with `xtick`.

Comment: do you know how to do it? thanks!!

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ: so your desired output is just to see spikes at every full hour?

Comment: possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704366/modify-date-ticks-for-pandas-plot

Comment: @Skandix, yes, I want to see ticks not only at 8, 10, 12 but every hour at 6,7,8,9,10 etc

Comment: @Skandix I tried `ax.set_xticks(intra_df.index)` but that does not work. Please post a solution if you find it. thanks again!

Comment: Anyway i got exactly the same plot using just `df.plot(
color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4)`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The problem is that while pandas in general directly wraps the matplotlib plotting methods, this is not the case for plots with dates. As soon as dates are involved, pandas uses a totally different numerical representation of dates and hence also uses its own locators for the ticks.

In case you want to use  `matplotlib.dates` formatters or locators on plots created with pandas you may use the `x_compat=True` option in pandas plots.

```
df.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4, x_compat=True)
```

This allows to use the `matplotlib.dates` formatters or locators as shown below.
Else you may replace `df.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4)` by

```
ax.plot(df.index, df.values, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4)
```

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 05:03', '2017-01-01 18:03', freq = 'min')
df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(idx)),  index = idx)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

ax.plot(df.index, df.values, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4)
#or use
df.plot(ax = ax, color = 'black', linewidth = 0.4, x_compat=True)
#Then tick and format with matplotlib:
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If the motivation to use pandas here is (as stated in the comments below) to be able to use `secondary_y`, the equivalent for matplotlib plots would be a twin axes `twinx`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 05:03', '2017-01-01 18:03', freq = 'min')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(len(idx), 2),0), 
                  index = idx, columns=list("AB"))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df["A"], color = 'black')
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.index, df["B"], color = 'indigo')

hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. maybe a workaround to keep Pandas doing the plots would be to get a regular Timestamp index instead of a pandas datetime?

Comment: I would like to keep the Pandas constructor because I use extensively the `secondary_y` argument of plot to show multiple times series...

Comment: I can't imagine any workaround for this. `matplotlib.dates` assumes the numeric axes to represent days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1. Only if the axes uses this datetime format, it will correctly tick and label the axes. On the other hand pandas will create its axes units depending on the data and use an appropriate locator for those units. The only alternative I could think of would be to manipulate the pandas formatters in use. I am not aware of any coherent way of doing this though.

Comment: The equivalent of secondary_y in matplotlib is to create a `twinx` and plot the second plot to that axes. This will in general cause 3 codelines compared to one, so it's not that bad.

Comment: Oh thats great. could you please add that to your answer then? just plot another random column. that would be a perfect solution

Comment: that is assume the data is `df = pd.DataFrame({'value1' : np.random.randn(len(idx)),
                   'value2' : np.random.randn(len(idx))},  index = idx)
df['value2'] = df['value2']* 1000`

Comment: something very strange is that I am not able to rotate the x-axis in the dual axis plot. Do you know how to make the hour labels vertical (rot = 90)? Thanks again for this amazing solution

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Here the easiest would be `fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Solution with pandas only

You can set ticks for every hour by using the timestamps of the `DatetimeIndex`. The ticks can be created by taking advantage of the [datetime properties](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.minute.html) of the timestamps.

```
import numpy as np   # v 1.19.2
import pandas as pd  # v 1.1.3

idx = pd.date_range('2017-01-01 05:03', '2017-01-01 18:03', freq='min')
series = pd.Series(np.random.randn(len(idx)), index=idx)

ax = series.plot(color='black', linewidth=0.4, figsize=(10,4))
ticks = series.index[series.index.minute == 0]
ax.set_xticks(ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks.strftime('%H:%M'));
```

[image: hour_ticks]