# How to display Hours on the x-axis using Prophet plot function

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

I'd like some assistance in using a more granular time-series in my Prophet forecast plots, specifically an Hour grain on the x-axis.
My data is aggregated for each Hour of the day.  In addition to the aggregated data, I create the necessary Prophet variables with:

```
ads_mod['y'] = ads_mod[target1]
ads_mod['ds'] = ads_mod['hour']
```

I then start the modeling process:

```
m = Prophet(interval_width=interval_width)
m.add_seasonality(name='hourly', period=1, fourier_order=30)
m.fit(ads_mod)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=1,freq='H') 
forecast = m.predict(future)
```

I plot the Forecast with:

```
fig = m.plot(forecast)
```

I have reviewed the actual code in the plot function and tried a variety of modifications to display the hour along with date(i.e., datetime value) on the x-axis, without success. 
In particular, I looked at the date transform:

```
fcst_t = fcst['ds'].dt.to_pydatetime()
```

After the transform, I see my data is now in the following format, with the Hour still included. 
A fragment of the plot is below and you see that on the x-axis the date(i.e., YYYY,MM,DD) is the only value displayed:

```
fcst_t[:10]
Out[277]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 1, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 2, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 3, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 4, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 5, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 6, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 7, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 8, 0),
       datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 2, 9, 0)], dtype=object)
```

[image: Plot Fragment]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
```

.... additional plot code here......

```
hours = mdates.HourLocator(interval = 1)
h_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(hours)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(h_fmt)
```

Here is the link:  [https://urldefense.com/v3/**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790378/how-to-get-ticks-every-hour**;!!M-nmYVHPHQ!cfpmWmLR0J5OMTJIH0aiEwrHWzsnD7pHJSBdVXxRTcAMK6mQ3v8K-FudC7uC6RN78uhTDCkD](https://urldefense.com/v3/__https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790378/how-to-get-ticks-every-hour__;!!M-nmYVHPHQ!cfpmWmLR0J5OMTJIH0aiEwrHWzsnD7pHJSBdVXxRTcAMK6mQ3v8K-FudC7uC6RN78uhTDCkD)$