# Plotting string type as x axis markers

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a string type on a X axis.

This is how my plot looks like.

[image]

I want it to set markers at full hours i.e. "XX:00" or half hours i.e. "XX:30".

Any suggestions please.

Thank you.

Comment: As you mention 'dataframe', probably you're referring to pandas: [how-to-get-ticks-every-hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790378/how-to-get-ticks-every-hour). E.g. with `mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M')` and `mdates.HourLocator(interval=0.5)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get ticks every hour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48790378/how-to-get-ticks-every-hour)