# Pandas Time Series DataFrame Plotting with Time Axis Control

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I see countless examples through blogs and on this site (see posts like [Modify date ticks for pandas plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704366/modify-date-ticks-for-pandas-plot))  of being able to use `matplotlib.dates` to control plotting of `pandas` dataframe plotting.  I am struggling to get similar behaviour:

```py
import pandas as pd
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import ticker

print(f'System info: {sys.version}')
print(f'Pandas Version: {pd.__version__}')
print(f'Matplotlib Version: {matplotlib.__version__}')

index = pd.date_range(start='12/21/19 10:43:00', end='2019-12-21 10:47:00', freq= '10s')

data = {'A': [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
              0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        'B': [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
              0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data)

ax = df.plot()

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.SecondLocator(interval=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
# ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```

The output of  my terminal is:

```
System info: 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Pandas Version: 0.25.3
Matplotlib Version: 3.1.2
```

[image: Output Plot]

I get no labels at all.  It seems as though `pandas` or `matplotlib` isn't converting to `datetime`, even though `date_range` produces `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you asked this, but if you use matplotlib to plot instead of Pandas I get your expected result.

See my modifications to your code below,

```
import pandas as pd
import sys
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import ticker

print(f'System info: {sys.version}')
print(f'Pandas Version: {pd.__version__}')
print(f'Matplotlib Version: {matplotlib.__version__}')

index = pd.date_range(start='12/21/19 10:43:00', end='2019-12-21 10:47:00', freq= '10s')

data = {'A': [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
              0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        'B': [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
              0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data=data)

#ax = df.plot()
```

Here I plot your data using matplotlib

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df['A'])
ax.plot(df.index, df['B'])

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.NullLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.SecondLocator(interval=15))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
# ax.get_figure().canvas.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's useful to know!  I like using pandas directly as it allows me to do other wonky things.  Such as `df.groupby('A')['B'].plot(style='o')` and color by groups in a single line.  I was trying to simplify my question to the basics of what wasn't working.