# Plot all data - Matplotlib - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a line chart with a "date_range" date list as x-axis and a list of integers "balance" as y axis

[image]

But when plot it omit some dates.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (4, 7), dpi = 70, constrained_layout = True)
ax = plt.plot(date_range, balance)
```

[image]

There are only 7 dates of 17, how i plot all data?

Comment: The data is all plotted, you just need to change the labels.

Comment: All the data has been plotted (you can see 17 changes of direction in the line chart), the labels on the axes are independent of the data items

Comment: what method i should use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modify date ticks for pandas plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704366/modify-date-ticks-for-pandas-plot)

Comment: It says pandas, but pandas uses matplotlib as the backend. The duplicate resolves the question with a matplotlib solution.

Comment: I solved it with ax.set_xticks(date_range)

Comment: That works if you have a limited number of ticks, the duplicate is a more robust solution, allowing the user to specify the tick interval for cases with many labels.