# How to increase the time step in charts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a function that reads csv and outputs me 12 graphs. But it displays the time with a very small interval.

Here's the function!

```
def Gr():
    df = pd.read_csv('DataSet.csv',)
    '''start = df['Time'].iloc[0]
    start = str(start)
    start1 = start.replace(':', '-')
    end = df['Time'].iloc[-1]
    end = str(end)
    end1 = end.replace(':', '-')
    index = pd.date_range(start = start1, end = end1, freq = "S")
    index = [pd.to_datetime(date, format='%H:%M:%S').date() for date in index] '''
    names = ['P', 'Filter', 'Answers', 'step','step2','Comulative', 'Delta_ema','ComulativePOC', 'Delta_P', 'Sum','SpeedUp', 'M' ]
    features = df[names]
    features.index = df['Time']
    axs = features.plot(subplots=True)
    cursor = MultiCursor(axs[1].get_figure().canvas, axs)
    plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.19, hspace=0.05, top=0.99, right=0.988, bottom=0.052, left=0.055)
    plt.show()
```

Here is a screenshot of the result of the functions. I circled the time at the bottom. I would like to increase the interval to at least once every 5 seconds or even 1 second.

[image]

Is it possible to do it this way ? Without a figure?

Comment: Setting `axs.set(xlim=(xmin, xmax))` should adjust the zoom level and therefore the displayed interval. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axis.html)

Answer (score 1):

you should uses something like this before your `plt.show()` line

```py
import matplotlib.dates as m_dates

ax = plt.gca() # get the current axis
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(m_dates.SecondLocator(interval=5)) # every five seconds
```

info about SecondLocator:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.SecondLocator

info dates in general:https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html

info ticks locating: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=ticks%20locator

Comment: I've tried a lot of your method. Unfortunately, nothing came up. There is either an error that generates 2030402 thousand ticks if I put less than 10000 in ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(m_dates.SecondLocator(interval=100000))   and if I put 10000 in interval, then I get an empty x-axis. What could this be related to ?

Comment: Here is the error: Locator attempting to generate 28654 ticks ([-1507.1555555555556, ..., 31656.03888888889]), which exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS (1000)

Comment: Do you have some data?? I'm a bit surprise. What are your initial and last time point data? Maybe you can try ```ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(m_dates.MinuteLocator(interval=1))``` and check whta that does?

Comment: In my csv, every seconds are represented starting from 10:00:00 ending at 21:00:00

Comment: I looked, there are 31 thousand lines

Comment: I think that is the origin of the problem, 11 hours multiply by 3600 makes 39600 seconds, and your maximum of ticks is 1000. you may want to split the csv in parts or use minutes locator

Comment: The minutes locator works the same way as the seconds locator. I have already tried and divided the csv. I took the first half hour - it's 256 lines and it still doesn't work with your method. Okay, I'll think and try something else. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry I cannot help much more

Comment: You've already given me a lot! Thanks for that!

Comment: Can you tell me something else ? I found out what .plot returns me matplotlib.dates.AxesSubplot object